# Node.js / nowjs - A lot of users

Tags: javascript, node.js, nowjs-sockets

I've made a server in nowjs, and with about 80 users online it get slow and sometimes people get disconnect. I've heared about that I have to change the workers count. But how to do it? and is it a solution? Or maybe there are another advices.

Comment: Ok i've done it. I'm kind of new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have hit a scaling issue, 80 users seems low to me.
Are you sure you are not doing any kind of logic on your server side that could be blocking ?
Any math or something that require too much time ?

If you have a scaling issue, you may need to horizontally scale you app. 
To do so you would have to use something like node cluster to have multiple workers handling the work, and a Redis or a Mongo used for handling shared the data, it might be possible to do using message in node cluster.

I've not push now.js that far yet. I don't know how it would handle in such a situation.

Comment: what about these clusters, is it work as one server app? and all I need is add some code, not change so much?

Comment: The only scenario in which you would have not much code to change is finding a logic bottleneck. Something you could cache or compute out of the event loop. Anything else is going to require some major changes.

Comment: All what server do is every 2 sec compare two users from array of them. And other things: receive/send text msgs from users then send every msg to mysql database. And every 10sec update some random code to database.

Comment: So you have 2 setInternvals and you make mysql queries on messages ?

Comment: yes, queries are for store user text msg, store tags, store new talks informations when it begin, and when it end, and some other small things. But it is mysql-side.

Comment: but messages are recv and send out of setInterval logic. It's about running server functions on client-side and client on server-side, like nowjs do.

Comment: YOu don't run server side function on the client, you call them. If what that function does, is a mysql query, then when it is complete it  will execute you client side callback. If you are doing a lot of call a the same time this could be you mysql not being able to handle so many query so fast. If that's the bottleneck and if what you store in mysql does not need to be persisted (saved) Redis would be a better option.

Comment: but mysql part of server is just storing what happening, main part of chat can work without it. So mysql cant slow down chat.

Comment: Maybe it's about my log file, because output of my server is kind of big and I made it saving to file.

Comment: MySQL is not the datastore of choice for a chat, mongo would be faster  and appropriate. But yeah you log file could be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned writing log data to file and is larger, make sure you're using right Node asynch file i/o so is not blocking -- can use with optional callbacks.  Better yet, creating a write stream is the way to go (Node is great for it's asynch file streaming capabilities).